# MySQL: Penalty for LEFT JOIN with no joiners...

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I'm curious to know what the query penalty will be for calling a `LEFT JOIN` with nothing to join to.

I have two tables: `main` has `.ID`, `.type` and `.info`, `additional` has `.ID` and `.more_info`

I'm running this query:

`SELECT main.*, additional.* FROM main LEFT JOIN additional ON main.ID = additional.ID`

I know full well that 70% of the time, I'm going to be querying for a `main.type` that *has no additional info* -- there is no entry in `additional` but due to restrictions, I always have to include the LEFT JOIN statement.

How much of a query penalty (time) will this result in -- if any?

E.G. Is:

`SELECT * FROM main WHERE type = 'no additional'`

going to be significantly faster than:

`SELECT main.*, additional.* FROM main LEFT JOIN additional ON main.ID = additional.ID WHERE main.type = 'no additional'`?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you benchmark it? There is no penalty for NOT getting matches. MySQL has to scan the indexes of the joined fields REGARDLESS to check if there are matches.

If anything, getting join results is actually the penalty, as now MySQL has to dig through the table file to bring back the results.